# How to get logged in user's name from App Service Hosted on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity

I have an app service hosted on azure. This is the code that runs on first page that loads.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            lblUserInfo.Text = $"Found User -- > {identity}";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            
            lblUserInfo.Text = "Name Unknown!";

        }
    }
```

When I run it locally, it correctly says "Name Unknown" in that label. On Azure the Authentication blade on the app service indicates that the service cannot be accessed without a login. In other words, the app can be accessed by people in the organization.

My understanding from the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user?view=netframework-4.8) is that HttpContext.Current.User can be used to fetch the user's name in the code. This is not working as the identity variable in the code is blank when I host on azure. The website label displays `"Found User --> "` when it runs on Azure.

**What else do I need to do in order to get the user's name in the code?**

Comment: What is the .Net and Visual Studio version you are using ?

Comment: The .NET version is 4.8 and VS2022. I am not sure if VS 2022 plays a role in it.

Comment: Confirming the details to repro the issue